# Range of error in linear regression

Tags: regression, least-squares, linear-model, projection

In linear regression whose matrix form is
$$Y = Xb + E$$
where $X=[X_1,X_2]$.

If the error of using only $X_1$ (i.e $ Y = X_1b+E$ ) is $x_1$, and the error of using $X_2$ (i.e $ Y=X_2b+E$) is $e_2$, what is the range the error using both columns, i.e $Y=[X_1,X_2]b + E$?

I tried to project $Y$ to $X_1$, $X_2$, and the $span\{X\}$ using Gram-Schmidt procedure, but I might overcomplicate the problem and haven't got anything yet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by the terms "error" and "range."  Are you looking for conclusions about probability models or bounds based on data?  Does your term "$b$" consistently represent a single quantity or does its meaning change each time it appears?  Is it intended to refer to estimates or true values?  Are you perhaps trying to ask about [model mis-specification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=model+mis+specification)?